# Do not show duplicate values ​in a cursor PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

Hi at this moment I am returning these values

```
--Group: Junior -- Name: Jared Ramirez -- Id Agent: 1
--Group: Junior -- Name: Jared Ramirez -- Id Agent: 1
--Group: Junior -- Name: Lilah Bailey -- Id Agent: 26
--Group: Junior -- NoNamebre: Lilah Bailey -- Id Agent: 26
--Group: Junior -- Name: Lilah Bailey -- Id Agent: 26
```

But I want to return only 1 for each agent number for example

```
--Grupo: Junior -- Nombre: Jared Ramirez -- Id Agente: 1
--Grupo: Junior -- Nombre: Lilah Bailey -- Id Agente: 26
```

```
DECLARE 
idCalls CALLS.CALL_ENTRY_ID%type;
idAgenteLlamada CALLS.ID_AGENT%type;

CURSOR c_Call (idCalls CALLS.CALL_ENTRY_ID%type) is
                                                SELECT ID_AGENT
                                                FROM CALLS                                                                                                
                                                WHERE CALL_ENTRY_ID = idCalls;

BEGIN
    OPEN c_Call (idCalls);
    FETCH c_Call INTO idAgentCall;
    WHILE c_Call %FOUND 
         LOOP
         dbms_output.put_line('--Group: '||usergroup||' -- Name: '|| userName|| ' -- Id Agent: ' || idAgentCall);
         FETCH c_Call INTO idAgentCall;
         END LOOP;
    CLOSE c_Call ;
END;
```

I have tried using `distinct` and `GROUP BY` but it still keeps returning the repeated values. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you execute this query in SQL plus then do you get multiple rows and if you get multiple rows for ID_AGENT, then can you try using DISTINCT and see if you are getting one row or multiple tows per agent.

```
SELECT ID_AGENT FROM CALLS WHERE CALL_ENTRY_ID = idCalls;
```

Comment: I used this ```SELECT DISTINCT ID_AGENT FROM CALLS WHERE CALL_ENTRY_ID = idCalls;
``` But even so it keeps returning the repeated ID_AGENT

Comment: Hi, try this in SQL plus and see that you get, SELECT DISTINCT TRUNC(ID_AGENT) FROM CALLS WHERE CALL_ENTRY_ID = idCalls;